# Assigning values error C

Tags: c, pointers, hashtable

I am new to C and I am having some trouble with pointers and values.

So I am making a hash table and there is an error with my insert function (The error is posted after the code):

```
typedef struct WordList {
   char *word;
   struct WordList *next;
} WordList;

typedef struct HashTable {
   int key;
   struct WordList *value;
   struct HashTable *next;
} HashTable;

#define TABLE_SIZE 8192

HashTable *table[TABLE_SIZE] = { NULL };

//Insert element
void insertElement(int key, char *word) {
   int i = 0;

   // check if key has already existed
   while((&(table[i]->key) != NULL) && (i < TABLE_SIZE)) {
      // !!!! ERROR HERE !!!! if(table[i]->key == key) { // if find key    
         // ... implementation

         return; // exit function and skip the rest
      }

      i++; // increment loop index 
   }

   // find a NULL slot and store key and value
   if(&(table[i]->key) == NULL) {
      // !!! ERROR HERE!!! table[i]->key = key;

      // ... implementation
   }
}

int main() {
   // test call
   insertElement(1, "blah\0");

   int i;

   for ( i=0; i < 10; i++)
   {
      printf("%d: ", i);

      struct HashTable *tableTemp = table[i];

      while (tableTemp != NULL)
      {
         printf("(%d)\n", tableTemp->key);
         tableTemp = tableTemp->next;
      }

      printf("\n");
   }

   return 0;
}
```

I use valgrind and this is the error I have with the assignment table[i]-> key = key

```
Invalid write of size 4
Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Comment: Address `0x0` is the null pointer; you're attempting to write a 4-byte value (probably an `int`) using a null pointer.  Like `int *p = 0; *p = 1;`.

Comment: Where do you allocate memory for `table[i]`? The array `table` is an array of *pointer* that you initialize to `NULL`, and if you don't make them point to any valid memory then you will get that error.

Comment: Why not just allocate table[size] and use dot notation?  Otherwise you have to malloc each one.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, address `0x0` is the null pointer; you're attempting to write a 4-byte value (probably an `int`) using a null pointer — like `int *p = 0; *p = 1;` but it probably isn't quite so blatant.

In your skeletal code, you have:

```
if (&(table[i]->key) == NULL) {
    // !!! ERROR HERE!!! table[i]->key = key;
```

Comments:

1. You should have shown the actual code for the error.  We have to guess because you haven't shown it.
2. You've just verified that the address of `table[i]->key` is a null pointer, which is going to lead to problems when you try to assign `table[i]->key = key;` to it.

In future, please provide enough of the real code that we can see your MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names and links for the same basic idea.